# Printing a MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
function MattsScript()
{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `ACCOUNTING` WHERE  `ACCTSTATUSTYPE` = "start" AND `Process_status` IS NULL LIMIT 0,100';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo $row['USERNAME'] . "<br />";
        echo $row['ACCTSTATUSTYPE'];
    }
}
```

I am trying to echo the results of a query. What I think is happening here is I am saving a query to a variable, the first 100 results (LIMIT 0,100) then using a loop to echo each row to the page.

However nothing is happening, no error and nothing written to the page.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure tha tyou have error reporting turned on?  Are you sure that `MattsScript` gets called?

Comment: Are you sure that fields names USERNAME and ACCTSTATUSTYPE exists?

Comment: The first result is ignored due to `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` right after `mysql_query`; are you sure you have multiple results ?

Comment: Oh, and you're doing mysql_fetch_assoc twice. No need for the first one.

Comment: Find example here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 3):

if you are expecting only one result remove the **while loop** if not leave the while loop and remove the line **$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);** before the while loop. Also make sure you are querying your database correctly.

Example: `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`